# How can I disable the audio for a specific scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this line :

```
AudioListener.pause = true;
```

The problem is that I have two scenes loaded, I'm loading another scene with the

```
LoadSceneMode.Additive
```

Then the audio pausing is effecting both scenes.

This is my full code for pausing/resuming the game. Index 0 is the Main Menu scene and index 1 is the Game scene. I have two scenes the Main Menu and the Game.

When I hit the escape key to the main menu I want to pause the audio in the Game scene and then when hitting the escape ley again back to the game I want to resume the audio in the game scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objsToDisable;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                AudioListener.pause = false;
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                AudioListener.pause = true;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;

                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
    }

    private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in objsToDisable)
        {
            if (go.name == "Cameras")
            {
                foreach(Transform child in go.transform)
                {
                    if(child.name == "Main Camera")
                    {
                        if (enabled == false)
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                go.SetActive(enabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned one possibility is to use [`AudioSource.mute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-mute.html) but of course you'd have to use it on all sources of according scene.

When you already know the index you can do e.g.

```
var scene = SceneManager.GetSceneAtBuildIndex(1);
if(scene.isValid)
{
    // Iterate through the scene Hierarchy and get all sources (also inactive/disabled ones)
    var audioSources = new List<AudioSource>();
    foreach (var root in scene.GetRootGameObjects())
    {
        audioSources.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>(true));
    }

    foreach(var source in audioSources)
    {
        source.mute = !enabled;
        //Or
        source.pause = !enabled;
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you could use the [`AudioMixer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixer.html) which I'd say is more convenient for this.

Here would simply but all the sources into a certain [`AudioMixerGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Audio.AudioMixerGroup.html) and make the volume an exposed parameter.

Then you can simply silent that entire group by using [`SetFloat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Audio.AudioMixer.SetFloat.html).

---

Btw be very careful with naming your method parameters like already existing fields/properties! Yes, they will be shadowed anyway but it only leads to confusion for you and other readers. There already is [`Behavior.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) which `MonoBehavior` and thus your class derives from.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `audio_source_name.mute = true` &/or `audio_source_name.Stop()`?

Example:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
            // AudioListener.pause = true;
            audio_source_name.mute = false;     // <--------
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
            // AudioListener.pause = true;
            audio_source_name.mute = false;     // <--------
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;

            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do it this way (Source: [Unity - Scripting API: AudioSource.mute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-mute.html)):

```
// Mutes-Unmutes the sound from this object each time the user presses space.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            audioSource.mute = !audioSource.mute;
    }
}
```

Comment: This disabled **one** certain `AudioSource` .. OPs question rather is: Can you disable all sound coming from a certain scene